# Optimize nested query to single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a (MySQL) table containing dates of the last scan of hosts combined with a report ID:

```
+--------------+---------------------+--------+
| host         | last_scan           | report |
+--------------+---------------------+--------+
| 112.86.115.0 | 2012-01-03 01:39:30 |      4 |
| 112.86.115.1 | 2012-01-03 01:39:30 |      4 |
| 112.86.115.2 | 2012-01-03 02:03:40 |      4 |
| 112.86.115.2 | 2012-01-03 04:33:47 |      5 |
| 112.86.115.1 | 2012-01-03 04:20:23 |      5 |
| 112.86.115.6 | 2012-01-03 04:20:23 |      5 |
| 112.86.115.2 | 2012-01-05 04:29:46 |      8 |
| 112.86.115.6 | 2012-01-05 04:17:35 |      8 |
| 112.86.115.5 | 2012-01-05 04:29:48 |      8 |
| 112.86.115.4 | 2012-01-05 04:17:37 |      8 |
+--------------+---------------------+--------+
```

I want to select a list of all hosts with the date of the last scan and the corresponding report id. I have built the following nested query, but I am sure it can be done in a single query:

```
SELECT rh.host, rh.report, rh.last_scan
FROM report_hosts rh
WHERE rh.report = (
    SELECT rh2.report
    FROM report_hosts rh2
    WHERE rh2.host = rh.host
    ORDER BY rh2.last_scan DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
GROUP BY rh.host
```

Is it possible to do this with a single, non-nested query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can do a `JOIN` in your query

```
SELECT x.*
FROM report_hosts x
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT host,MAX(last_scan) AS last_scan FROM report_hosts GROUP BY host
) y ON x.host=y.host AND x.last_scan=y.last_scan
```

Your query is doing a filesort, which is very inefficient. My solutions doesn't. It's very advisable to create an index on this table

```
ALTER TABLE `report_hosts` ADD INDEX ( `host` , `last_scan` ) ;
```

Else your query will do a filesort twice.

Comment: This seems reasonable. Thank's for the index!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select from the `report_hosts` table only once then you could use a sort of 'RANK OVER PARTITION' method (available in Oracle but not, sadly, in MySQL). Something like this should work:

```
select h.host,h.last_scan as most_recent_scan,h.report
from
(
select rh.*,
case when @curHost != rh.host then @rank := 1 else @rank := @rank+1 end as rank,
case when @curHost != rh.host then @curHost := rh.host end
from report_hosts rh
cross join (select @rank := null,@curHost = null) t
order by host asc,last_scan desc
) h
where h.rank = 1;
```

Granted it is still nested but it does avoid the 'double select' problem. Not sure if it will be more efficient or not - kinda depends what indexes you have and volume of data.